# how many children do you have a node I selected?

Tags: extjs

I've been looking but have not located anything,  and I can know how many children have a node I selected?

Greetings and thank you....

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are working with a treeStore am I right?

If so, according the doc on [NodeInterface](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface) you can use the attribute [childNodes](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-property-childNodes) and use it as an array.

So `childNodes.length`.

Just a note, be careful if you use lazy loading, the childNodes might be empty if it's not loaded already.

Comment: that's exactly what happens, "Just a note, be careful if you use lazy loading, the childNodes might be empty if it's not loaded already.".

as I can correct it?.

Greetings and thank you....

Answer (score 0):

that's exactly what happens, "Just a note, be careful if you use lazy loading, the childNodes might be empty if it's not loaded already.".

as I can correct it?.

Greetings and thank you....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the lazyLoading functionality, you need to do an expand before accessing `childNodes` (as this will cause asynchronous call, you'll need to do your count in the `callback` of `expand` method).

Else, you need to disable the lazyLoading by setting the following property in your tree store:

```
autoLoad: false,
rootVisible: false,
root: {
    expanded: false,
    children: []
// <- Inline root
}
```